# Remove line break from div element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am currently working on a page using the CSS grid layouts, however I ran into a problem with `div` elements in which they automatically insert a line break into the output above and below the text.

Is there any way to easily remove these with CSS?

I tried changing the `div` element to `span`, but nothing changed. I also set the `div` elements to `display: inline;` but that didn't work either.

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 110px 200fr 200fr 80px;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.grid-heading {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-sidebar {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.grid-content1 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.grid-content2 {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.grid-footer {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>
  Home
</title>
<head>

</head>
<html>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-heading">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-sidebar">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-content1">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-content2">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-footer">5</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: _"a problem with div elements in which they automatically insert a line break into the output above and below the text"_ - that's not a line break, that's the default margin-top and -bottom the h1 element gets from the browser stylesheet. Overwrite/null those, if you don't like the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div{ 
display:inline-block;
}
```

Display:inline; should have worked

Comment: I tried that already, just forgot to include it. Thanks though!

Comment: OK but maybe you could try putting display:inline; for all of the elements and then when you want them to be in a different line use the <br> tag. That worked when I tried to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

you might need to include a screenshot... but try removing the padding on the grid-item class as well as adjusting the grid-gap. also keep in mind that default styling for most browsers includes margin and padding on most items.

Comment: I think this answer could be more helpful if you provided examples / pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

i thing it's  `grid-gap`  remove this style

```
 .grid-container {
      grid-gap: 0;
    }

    h1, p {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

than working fine https://jsfiddle.net/z7y2qaa7/